# Why is my solution to stars and bars wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, combinations

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two

I can see that in case 2, where it is possible to have bars in the same gaps, that there are $n+1$ gaps and $k-1$ bars. But surely the binomial coefficient of ${n+1}\choose{k-1}$ (number of ways of filling $n+1$ gaps with $k-1$ bars) discounts possibilities where bars are in the same gap? My formula is $$\frac{(n+1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$

As we have $n+1$ choices for position of each bar and the ordering of bars doesn't matter.

Moreover, how is the binomial coefficient ${n+1}\choose{k-1}$ $=$ ${n+k-1}\choose{n}$? It doesn't work for the case $ n= 7, k=4$?

Comment: If $k=3,n=2$ you get $\frac {3^2}2$ which isn't even an integer.

Comment: The article you link to says the $\textit {multinomial symbol} \left(\binom {n+1}{k-1}\right)$ equals the $\textit {binomial symbol} $  $\binom {n+k-1}n$  The proof supplied in the article is hard to beat for elegance.

Comment: I do not think Wikipedia is as clear as it should be on the stars and bars in  theorem two.  I would simply say you have $n$ stars and $k-1$ bars to put in any order (e.g. bars are allowed next to each other), so ${n+k-1 \choose n}={n+k-1 \choose k-1}$ ways of doing this depending on whether you choose the stars' positions first or the bars' positions  first.

Comment: @lulu You should not refer to $\left(\!\binom {n}{k}\!\right)$ as the "multinomial symbol". The multinomial symbol is $\binom{n}{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k} = \frac{n!}{n_1!\,n_2!\dotsm n_k!}$. You sometimes hear $\left(\!\binom {n}{k}\!\right)$ referred to as the *multichoose number* or the *multiset number*, of which I think the second is more clear.

Comment: @MishaLavrov  You are correct.  Oddly, I thought I was quoting from the wiki article, but I just checked and they, correctly, used $\textit {multiset number}$.

Comment: @lulu could you explain why, conceptually, my formula doesn't work?

Comment: Work it through for the example I wrote, $k=3,n=2$.  Those numbers are small enough so that you can write it all out explicitly.

Comment: Oh right. There are multiple unique ways of getting to the same combination using independent selection. So dividing by $(k-1)!$ would be wrong. Thanks

Comment: No problem.  At first glance, your formula looks sensible...these things are annoyingly unintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $k-1$ bars into $n+1$ gaps, putting $k-1$ balls into $n+1$ bins, and making a list of $n+1$ non-negative integers that sum to $k-1$: these are all equivalent problems, and you can draw a direct link between the solution to one and the solution to another.

But just doing bars in gaps, $(n+1)^{k-1}$ is the number of ways you can put the bars into gaps *if it matters which bars are in which gap.* You can confirm this with some (very small) test cases, for example write down all the ways $3$ numbered bars go in $2$ numbered gaps and all the ways $2$ numbered bars go in $3$ numbered gaps.

With stars and bars, the bars are a fictitious device in the first place. Draw just one of the possible ways of distributing the bars (with a number on each bar), showing where the stars are too, and see what result (grouping of stars you get). Now renumber the bars and see what groups of stars you get. Do the numbers on the bars make any difference?

So  $(n+1)^{k-1}$ is too large. Can you fix this by dividing it by something? There are $(k-1)!$ ways to distribute the numbers when each of the first $k-1$ gaps is occupied by a bar. But there is only one way to put all the bars in the first gap. So you don’t have a nice relationship where every outcome you want to count is represented by exactly $M$ of the outcomes you have.

Faced with a dilemma like that, the best choice is to throw out everything and start over, trying to come up with a different way of attempting the problem.

I don’t even think of stars and bars as a process of “filling gaps.”  I think of it as we have two kinds of objects, $k-1$ of one kind and $n$ of another, and I want to put them all in a row from left to right. If I only care what type of object is in each place in the row, there are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to do this. Then I call the first kind of object a bar and the second kind a star and see what grouping of stars I get.

Answer (score 1):

I also thought that the formula should be $(n+1)^{(k-1)}/(k-1)!$.

But this is where I and you are wrong . Assume that $n=100$ and $k=3$. This means that we will be using $2$ bars to divide these $100$ elements. Since these bars are indistinguishable,  when the bar is at $2$ different positions, it indeed is correct that we are counting the permutation twice and hence there is a need to divide it by $2$.

But in the case where the two bars are at the same position, $101^2$ is counting such positions only once and therefore, these positions should not have been divided by $2$.

Therefore, since these $101$ positions were erroneously counted as $101/2$, we need to compensate by adding $101/2$ to $101^2/2$, giving us
$$
 \frac{101^2}{2}+\frac{101}{2} = \frac{102\cdot 101}{2} 
$$
which is the same result as the one we would have gotten by using the correct formula.